# Attributes vs variables namespace

Tags: python, class, attributes, namespaces, instance-variables

confusions in OOPs

1. why 'var' is not taking the global value in function as it is taking in class
2. can i create a local variable like 'a' in classes (say,c)?
3. why cant define class's attribute inside class body , like the way i done in function?
4. why 'f.a' is not callable but clss.c is callable? ( both assigned similarly )'''

(i am a beginner , my only option to ask and clear my concepts is to ask online python community for help
bcz i m learning online).

```
#error statements commented out
var=10
def fun():
    #var=var*10
    a=10
    fun.b=20
fun()
print(var)
#print(a)
print(fun.b)
#print(fun.a)


class clss:
    var=var*var
    c=10
    #clss.d=20
#print(c)
#print(clss.d)
print(clss.var)
print(clss.c)
```

Comment: There's a lot going on here. I suggest you break up your question into four different questions (each of which would have a different duplicate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this UnboundLocalError occur (closure)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/why-does-this-unboundlocalerror-occur-closure)

Comment: "why 'var' is not taking the global value in function as it is taking in class" because class bodies are special cases, and this is one of those special things about the class body scope.

Comment: Duplicate of point #3: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34558324/2988730

Comment: "can i create a local variable like 'a' in classes (say,c)?" you *are* doing that, in a sense, it's just that *the local variables of the class body namespace get turned into the class object namespace*. That is how class definitions work

Comment: "why cant define class's attribute inside class body , like the way i done in function?" because the class *doesn't exist yet (or the corresponding variable it is trying to refer to) when the class body is executed. On the other hand, a function already exists by the time it is called and the body executes

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46018872/2988730

Comment: "why 'f.a' is not callable but clss.c is callable? ( both assigned similarly )''' Because , **class definitions are not function definitions**. the **whole point** of a class definitions is to create the *class namespace*. That namespace is *the accessible attributes of the class object*. Functions dont work like this at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'm unable to close as a dupe because OP originally had the tag python-3.8 instead of just python. If you were to close this question, I could update the list of dupes to address all of OP's concerns

Comment: @MadPhysicist oh, I just voted to close as too broad... I'm sure someone else will come along shorts

Comment: Also note, "callable" is the wrong terminology here. Attributes either exist (are defined) or not. *Neither* are callable in this case. Callable means you can *call it like a function*, i.e `mycallable(arg)`